# How to replace columnar values in R between 2 numbers

Tags: r, analytics

I have imported a simple CSV file into a data frame. In a particular column, I would like to replace all values under 15.0 with 15.0, all values above 25.0 with 25.0, and all values between 15.0 and 25.0 with 20.0.

The below snippet works well for the first task, and switching the directional sign and replacing '15' with '25' works fine for the second task.

```
ff$temp[ ff$temp<15 ] <- 15
```

How can I accomplish replacing the values between 15 and 25 with 20?

Comment: `within(ff, temp[temp > 15 & temp < 25] <- 20)`

Comment: @RichardScriven If you enter your comment as an answer I will accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the same premise, just with a second logical operator to catch the "between" values.

For example,

```
> ff <- data.frame(temp = c(14, 17, 19, 24, 30))
> within(ff, temp[temp > 15 & temp < 25] <- 20)
#   temp
# 1   14
# 2   20
# 3   20
# 4   20
# 5   30
```

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to get that logical operator in between, this spells it out. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

```
 set.seed(25)
 v1 <- sample(5:35, 25, replace=TRUE)
  c(15, 20, 25)[cut(v1, breaks=c(-Inf, 15, 25, Inf), labels=FALSE)]
  #[1] 20 25 15 25 15 25 20 15 15 15 15 20 25 20 25 15 20 25 20 25 15 20 15 15 15
```

Comment: As an R newbie, Richard's comment answer seems more straight forward to me, though I do also understand what you have contributed. Many thanks.

Comment: @car of the cdr  I used `cut` because you mentioned about >2 replacement conditions.

Comment: @carofthecdr, this is the correct answer and thus should be accepted as one. Richards answer solving only one problem out of 3

Comment: David Arenburg. It is okay.  I think @car of the cdr is new to R and still needs some time to understand the functions.

Comment: As I look to do the same to another column, I find that I require 4 replacement categories, and this works well. Thanks again.

Comment: @car of the cdr If you need 4 replacement categories, you should change the `breaks` for example suppose, you need one more category say `30`, `breaks=c(-Inf, 15,25,30, Inf)`

Comment: Yep, I had pieced that together, but thanks for turning me on to it.